# Hutchinson-type algorithm for efficient computation of trace of inverse of non symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, random-matrices, approximation-algorithms, algorithmic-randomness

Let $A$ be an invertible $N$-by-$N$ matrix, for some large $N$ (say $N = 10^6$). Suppose the only thing we know how to do is apply $A$ to a vector, i.e compute matrix-vector products $Az$.

> **Question.**
>   What is a cheap (i.e with complexity $\mathcal O(N)$) randomized procedure for computing $\text{tr}(A^{-1})$ ?

Note that naively, $\text{tr}(A^{-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^Ne_i^TA^{-1}e_i$, which involves $N$ matrix-vector products, plus the cost of inverting precomputing $A^{-1}$, for a total cost of $\Theta(N^3)$.